# Changing the image breaks link

Tags: php, flash

I was having this:

```
<object id="FlashID" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="66" height="63">
    <param name="movie" value="<?=FLASH ?>/icon_about.swf" />
    <param name="FlashVars"  value="myLink=<?=FRONTEND_URL?>/about-us" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="swfversion" value="9.0.45.0" />
    <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
    <param name="expressinstall" value="<?=FRONT_URL ?>/js/expressInstall.swf" />
    <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="<?=FLASH ?>/icon_about.swf" width="66" height="63">

      <!--<![endif]-->
      <param name="FlashVars"  value="myLink=<?=FRONTEND_URL?>/about-us" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
      <param name="swfversion" value="9.0.45.0" />
      <param name="expressinstall" value="<?=FRONT_URL ?>/js/expressInstall.swf" />
      <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
      <div class="flash" style="width:400px;">
        <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>

        <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
      </div>
      <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
```

And everything waas going good. Flash was perfect and link was working. Then i changed the flash image and now link is not working!!.

Please help

Comment: Can you please explain what's `the flash image`?

Comment: So you can see the movie, but the link is not working?

Comment: As far as I understand `<param name="FlashVars"  value="myLink=<?=FRONTEND_URL?>/about-us" />` sends the link's value to the flash file and the flash file use it to create the link.
The flash file creates the link, you've changed the flash file - which probably doesn't create the link.

Comment: is there any way in php or js or something so that i can do it without going into the swf file!!..

Comment: not that I know, sorry